# How to Change Web service Address at Runtime?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, app-config

I'm using a webservice in my wpf application. 
and set it's URL Behavior to Dynamic, so I have an entry in app.config file like below :

```
<MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="MyApp_WebReference_OnlineUsersService" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://192.168.35.28/OnlineUsersService.asmx</value>
  </setting>
</MyApp.Properties.Settings>
```

I need to change server address dynamically, for example from `192.168.35.28` to `192.168.35.26`.
Question is : how can I change the contents of `<value>` tag at runtime?

thanks alot :)

Comment: @Micky sorry ,yeah, the whole project it's WPF and just one part of it needs communication with server, so it was better if i called it WCF.

Comment: Ah actually I see you are using .asmx files so that's old-skool web-services pre-WCF

Comment: What do you mean by _"tag"_?

Comment: @Micky I want to change content of value tag, this string : http://192.168.35.28/OnlineUsersService.asmx

Comment: @mr.dev.eloper you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var service = new MyApp.OnlineUsersService();
service.Url = "http://192.168.35.28/OnlineUsersService.asmx";
```

If what you're actually doing is specifying the url for a different path then I'd suggest using config transformation (App.Release.Config) to change the url before packaging.